# Looking for usage details on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to look for reports on my Amazon S3 usage, but Amazon only provides simple summary on the usage, such as amount of storage / transfer in a particular month. I need to have a breakdown of these data by files, for example:

- abc.mp3   : 123 GET request / 0.12Mb transferred
- hello.mp4 : 345 GET request / 0.32Mb transferred
- fun.docx  : 834 GET request / 0.20Mb transferred

Also, I need to know where do these GET request coming from, so I can better monitor and control on the S3 usage. For example:

abc.mp3:

- 53 GET request from http://www.example.com/music/page1.html
- 70 GET request from http://www.example.com/music/page2.html

Any tools / method on achieving these? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable S3 access logs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html

Then you should be able to parse the logs for the information you want. Once you start getting logs there are many options for parsing them, here are a few that I found with a quick search:

[s3stat](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/s3stat)

[s3-logs-analyzer](https://github.com/ogdch/s3-logs-analyzer)

[Loggly S3 support](https://www.loggly.com/docs/s3-logs/)

Comment: Thanks so much, let me try it out